# Перезагрузка <div> с графиком после смены таба

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, dygraph

Собственно, в чем затруднение. На странице есть два таба. На каждом из них по два

`div`'а на котором отрисовываются графики через `Dygraph`.
При загрузке страницы первый таб отображает графики как надо, при переходе на 2 - графиков нет.

Однако, как только я делаю увеличение или уменьшение размеров страницы - они появляются (пропадая на предыдущем табе).

Осознаю, что вроде как надо делать `resize()` выбранного `div`, но не понимаю как.
Сам плагин на табы:

```
(function($) {
$(function() {

    $('ul.tabs__caption').each(function(i) {
        var storage = localStorage.getItem('tab' + i);
        if (storage) {
            $(this).find('li').removeClass('active').eq(storage).addClass('active')
                .closest('div.tabs').find('div.tabs__content').removeClass('active').eq(storage).addClass('active');

        }
    });

    $('ul.tabs__caption').on('click', 'li:not(.active)', function() {
        $(this)
            .addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
            .closest('div.tabs').find('div.tabs__content').removeClass('active').eq($(this).index()).addClass('active');
        var ulIndex = $('ul.tabs__caption').index($(this).parents('ul.tabs__caption'));
        localStorage.removeItem('tab' + ulIndex);
        localStorage.setItem('tab' + ulIndex, $(this).index());
    });

});
})(jQuery);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/268215/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема не в табах. Такое обычно происходит, потому что у дивов в скрытом табе во время инициализации графиков как бы не вычислены размеры. По ресайзу плагин, который строит графики, считывает их заново. Попробуйте поиграться с инициализацией графиков, возможно там в опциях есть какие-то параметры на этот случай. Или же, например, задать дивам position отличный от static или явные высоту и ширину в стилях. Еще можно попробовать при переключении табов вручную триггерить 'resize' эвент у окна, который по идее слушает плагин:

```
//в вашем скрипте
window.onTabToggle = function () {
   window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
}

//изменения в плагине
$('ul.tabs__caption').on('click', 'li:not(.active)', function() {
    if (typeof onTabToggle === 'function') {
        onTabToggle();
    }
    ....
```

Comment: Попробовал поменять позиции и ширину/высоту у дива, но не помогло. 
Не подскажите, как можно сделать триггер на изменение таба?

Comment: @Depressa, плагин, что вы привели в вопросе, внешний или самописный?

Comment: внешний (небольшие косметические изменения с именами параметров и тд)

Comment: @Depressa, я имею в виду, можете ли вы в проекте его редактировать, или он подключается как внешний. Если можете, то добавте прямо в обработчик клика вызво какого-либо колбэка. По хорошему плагин надо бы оформить как jquery-плагин. Но по-быстрому можно просто проверять наличие глобальной функции и вызывать ее. Это не очень хорошая практика, конечно. Изменил код в ответе, попробуйте так.

Comment: Все, поиграл с алертами, и примерно осознал в какой момент идет resize и вызывается функция . Спасибо!

Comment: @Depressa, ой да, onTabToggle нужно вызывать после всего, что делается по клику)